# OpenCVSharp memory leaks

Tags: c#, opencv, memory-leaks

I use OpenCVSharp in my WPF app. I have a static function that creates `ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>` from list of mats:

```cs
public static ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> FromMatToBitmap(List<OpenCvSharp.Mat> mats)
{
    var bitmaps = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
    foreach (var mat in mats)
    {
        using (var ms = mat.ToMemoryStream())
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze();
            bitmaps.Add(bitmap);
        }
    }
    return bitmaps;
}
```

Now I have memory leak problems and ran Preformance Profiler to check out memory usage. As I understand the problem is with the `mat.ToMemoryStream()` method (because there is no `ImEncode` calls in my function):
[image: diagnostics]

Maybe I do something wrong there. Would be greatful for any help!
(I also Release and Dispose this mats after transforming them into bitmaps)

Comment: The way to handle memory leaks is to run a *memory profiler* and see if you can spot any managed objects leaking. But it is possible that OpenCL is leaking unmanaged memory, and that is much harder to detect with a memory profiler. It is also possible that the issue is in the library, and that you cannot fix yourself.

Comment: @JonasH I should kill myself then

Comment: I would start with the memory profiler :p. That is also useful to ensure there actually is a leak since it allow you to trigger a GC. Just checking memory usage in task manager is not a reliable way to spot leaks. If that does not help it might be useful to try to isolate the problem, setup a small test to reproduce the problem, start removing code until the problem disappear.